# i have a pong game made in unity and the ball never stop after a goal

Tags: javascript, unity-game-engine

i have a pong game made in unity and the ball never stop after a goal

this is script that i use for the ball

```
public class Ball extends MonoBehaviour {

    public var ballVelocity : float = 1000;

    public var rb : Rigidbody;

    public var isPlay : boolean ;
    public var randInt : int;

    var audioPong : AudioSource;

    function Awake()
    {       
        audioPong = GetComponent.<AudioSource>();
        rb = gameObject.GetComponent(Rigidbody);
        randInt = UnityEngine.Random.Range(1,3);
    }


    function FixedUpdate(){

        if(Input.GetMouseButton(0) == true && isPlay == false) {

            transform.parent = null;
            isPlay = true;
            rb.isKinematic = false;

            if(randInt == 1){
                rb.AddForce(new Vector3(ballVelocity, 0, 0));
            }
            if(randInt == 2){
                rb.AddForce(new Vector3(-ballVelocity, 0, 0));
            }               }
    }


    function OnCollisionEnter(col : Collision) {
        audioPong.Play();
    }

}
```

Comment: which language is it?

Comment: [Unityscript](http://wiki.unity3d.com/index.php/UnityScript_versus_JavaScript) @NinaScholz

Comment: javascript @NinaScholz

Answer (score 0):

Try setting the angularDrag property of the RigidBody to some value. See [the documentation](http://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Rigidbody-angularDrag.html) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

As far as I can tell, you don't have anything that tell the ball to stop. Where ever the goals are, give them collider components and the tag Goal. Then in the ball script you showed, check in the collisions for if the ball collided with the a goal, and if it did, stop the ball.

```
function OnCollisionEnter( col : Collision ){
    if (col.gameObject.tag == "Goal"){
        GetComponent(Rigidbody).velocity = Vector3(0,0,0);
        //then you can also give points, reset the ball and all that good stuff
    }
    audioPong.Play();
 }
```